# arcgis geocode api assuming storage of results when app is not storing

Tags: arcgis

I'm not even storing the results in a constant/in the app's memory at this point. Still getting this response. How do I get the api to understand I'm not storing the results permanently ?

full request:

```
const getEm = async (address) => {
await fetch(`https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?f=json&token=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ARCGIS_API_KEY}&address=${address}&forStorage=false&maxResults=1`)}
```

full response:

```
{
  "error": 
  {
   "code":403,
   "extendedCode":-2147220989,
   "message":"Token is valid but access is denied.",
   "details":["User does not have permissions to store geocoding results."]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems that the token you are using is set for storage.

When you set the services for your api key, you can choose the geocoding type: stored, not stored

[here the two different types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udYYI.jpg)